# Disk partitions

Tags: windows

Sorry if I missed the right forum, I was confused where to post this question.
I'm not an expert in systems and stuff, but I guess someone of you can help me with deciding which one partition should I use for Windows 10, and should I delete some of those partitions (I bought second-hand laptop).

I was in Windows 10 installation process and I'm confused which partition to choose for Windows 10, and what all those partition mean and is it better to delete them.

pic 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB2pn.jpg
pic 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0krn.jpg
pic 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzYUb.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty clear from the pictures that the partition meant for you to install stuff in is partition 7: Windows, which is also the biggest one.

Wrt. to the other ones, RECOVERY is used for when you break something and need to reinstall the OS, so best to not touch it. The other ones are small, and while it's not 100% clear what MSR stands for, the fact remains that the risk that you break something here is not really worth ~ 1GB additional disk space.